# Sliding menu mapview issue

Tags: android, google-maps, slidingmenu

I am using sliding menu in my application. One of my menu item is google map v2. When I open sliding menu from mapview, the black background will occur in my sliding menu. Why does the black background appear?

Comment: share your relevant code with screen shot ...:)

Comment: It comes from http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4639 or http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4659

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem(sliding menu + map view)...cant remove the black screen...
but there is a work around... what u can do is load your activity with the menu open [image]